# javascript creates new date minus one day

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I tried to set a jquery datepicker with a determinated date but when I create a new date for set the widget, javascript throw me one day minus

Code:

```
new Date('2016-04-14')
```

Result:

```
Wed Apr 13 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)
```

[***jsfiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/0u4te70y/)

Comment: `2016-04-14 00:00:00 UTC` is the same as `2016-04-13 17:00:00 GMT-7` (notice how US time here is 7 hours from midnight)

Comment: `date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [read the fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, they are equivalent) is **strongly discouraged** due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

You should probably go with `new Date(2016, 3, 14)` (3 because the month integer is zero-based). This will create a date in your timezone at midnight, April 14.

Comment: what would be the fool proof thing here?getting it from the server side?

Comment: @techie_28 that totally depends on your requirements

Comment: if users are in many different time zones can we have a way which suits all?

Comment: @techie_28 again, that depends on what you want to do. Do you want users to use dates in their browser's timezone, a timezone of their choosing or a specific, global timezone? I feel you should probably ask a full StackOverflow question if you need actual answers

Comment: its here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590873/consistent-client-side-date-timestamp-using-javascript

Answer (score 3):

To get the UTC(GMT) time use `.toUTCString()` instead of the default `.toString()`.

If you want to create local time midnight date from string, use iso8601 like `2016-04-01T00:00:00-07:00`. Note the timezone offset.