# Consistent Client Side Date/timestamp using JavaScript(considering TimeZones)

Tags: javascript, client-side

My question is regarding this quote from the manual about dates in JavaScript:

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
>   Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies.

`new Date('2016-04-14')` output for a user was `Wed Apr 13 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)` upon which he had to use `.toUTCString()`.

How to handle this if the users are in many different time zones?

Comment: use timestamp `new Date().getTime()` rather than the string for storage and comparisons

Comment: that way we do not need to use  `.toUTCString()` & other such functions?

Comment: Unless you only want to display (for that also you can use libraries for formatting), I don't see any reasons to use other functions.

Comment: I see.. so `.getTime()` would return consistent results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date().getTime();` returns an integer value as the time on client's machine since **1970 Jan 1**.

Since this is an integer value, it will be agnostic of locales, browser version, different browsers (IE, Chrome, Mozilla, or anything).

So, this should give you consistent results in terms of time on client's machine **as long as client's timezone is known**.

You can fetch client's timezone offset by using [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) API

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

This together with `new Date().getTime();` should give you consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
 new Date().getTime();
```

it will return you a milisecond time stamp since 1970-01-01 for the current time zone that the client is in. This can then be converted back to a date in any language.

This would be a better standard way to pass the date around if you are sending it to and from servers and between clients. As millisecond timestamp ts converted in timezone a will convert to 01/01/2010 and in timezone b will convert to 01/01/2010 as they are taken from 1970-01-01

Hope this makes sence